# problem authorization headers Pusher/Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, pusher-js

after installing pusher when i added

```
Echo.connector.pusher.config.auth.headers.Authorization=`Bearer ${state.userToken}`;
```

i got this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dn8O.png)

this is my app.js and bootstrap.js

```
setUser(state,user){
            state.user = user 
            Echo.connector.pusher.config.auth.headers.Authorization=`Bearer ${state.userToken}`;
        },
```

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
    host: window.location.hostname + ":8000",
    authEndpoint: "/api/broadcasting/auth",
    csrfToken: token.content ,
    auth:{
        headers:{Authorization: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userToken'))}
    }

});
```

anyone can help me pls ?

I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Check this ```Echo.connector.pusher.config``` and make sure auth objects exists only you are trying to access the property ```headers```

Comment: worked now ! 
but now i have an other problem , laravel echo not listen to the event !